# dataset not found in R data package I created

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen

I am building an R package that includes several datasets. I have the datasets saved as .RData objects in my "data" folder, and each dataset has documentation generated using `roxygen2`. When I install the package, load it and try to call a dataset,

```
devtools::install_github("jamesmartherus/nhldata")
library(nhldata)

data(teams)
```

I get this error:

```
In data("teams") : data set ‘teams’ not found
```

Here is the content of my DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: nhldata
Title: Easy Access to Basic NHL Data 
Version: 0.1.0
Authors@R: person("James", "Martherus", email = "james@martherus.com",
                  role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: Includes several datasets of NHL statistics including skater, goalie, and team statistics by season.
Depends: R (>= 3.5.0)
License: MIT
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.1.1
Encoding: UTF-8
```

and here is a minimal version of my documentation file:

```
\docType{data}
\name{teams}
\alias{teams}
\title{NHL Team Statistics 2007-2019}
\format{A data frame with 362 rows and 28 variables:
\describe{
  \item{team}{Team name}
  \item{season}{Season}
  . . .
}}
\source{
\url{http://corsica.hockey/team-stats/}
}
\usage{
data(teams)
}
\description{
A dataset containing season-level statistics for NHL teams for all
game states (5v5, PP, PK). Includes regular season.
}
\keyword{datasets}
```

Why can't I access the datasets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R prefers its datasets (things within `./data/`) to have a literal `.rda` file ending.

I cloned your repo and ran `devtools::check(...)`, and among other things saw:

```
   Subdirectory 'data' contains no data sets.
```

When I renamed all `.Rdata` files to `.rda` and reloaded, it works.

Comment: Interesting, thanks - the packaging book by Hadley Wickham at (http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) says use .RData, but I discovered the exact solution you mentioned through trial and error as well. Do you know if the preference/requirement for .rda is documented anywhere?

Comment: The [*Writing R Extensions - Data in Packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages) section (perhaps "the one true reference") does specifically list both `.RData` and `.rda` (case-specific here), so it's also possibly a case issue (`.Rdata` versus `.RData`). I'm running on windows at the moment which seems to exacerbate or mask any type of case-sensitivity issue.